# Reasons for Resultset closed with HibernatePersistenceProvider

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

There is a problem randomly occuring problem regarding a Resultset, which is closed in my application.

Hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans is activated, and sometimes if you do multiple calls on a service which triggers the lazy loading of data, I get the exception "Resultset is closed."

What could be the reasons for a closed Resultset? Too many connections to the database (which is mysql)? I didn't configure any connection-pool settings.